# Finding the tangent hyperplane to a function at a given point

Tags: multivariable-calculus, jacobian

Given a function $f : \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$ and a point $p$ in the domain, how would you find the equation of the tangent hyperplane to the surface at point $p$?

We know that if $h \to 0$, then the Jacobian matrix $J_f(p)h = 0$. Can we use this to find the equation of the hyperplane? Maybe something along the lines of $J_f(p) \cdot [x_i - p_i]^{\text{T}} = c$?

Comment: Isn't this the job of the gradient $\nabla f$?

Comment: @DanUznanski Sorry, can you explain the difference between $\nabla f$ and the Jacobian, and what they mean mathematically? The Jacobian is also sometimes written using [that notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacobian_matrix_and_determinant#:~:text=common%20notations%20include) apparently.

Comment: Oh.  the jacobian is apparently the ...almost gradient of a vector valued function, which is to say that the jacobian of a function $f : \mathbb R^n \rightarrow \mathbb R$ is simply the function's gradient, or rather its transpose?

Comment: @DanUznanski Looks like it's the transpose (I looked up on Wiki), so I don't think it makes much of a difference. And the matrix multiplication looks more natural using the Jacobian.

Comment: @dictatemetokcus Don't worry absolutely and I am very happy to help you. I have done a recent edit.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The equation of a tangent hyperplane (tangent plane in $\Bbb R^3$) to a function $f$ in a point $P_0\in\mathbb{R}^n$, (let be $n=3$) assuming that all conditions of differentiability are satisfied, is:

$$\left(\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}\right)_{P_0}(x-x_0)+\left(\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}\right)_{P_0}(y-y_0)+\left(\frac{\partial f}{\partial z}\right)_{P_0}(z-z_0)=0$$
$$\iff (\boldsymbol\nabla f)_{P_0}\cdot (\mathbf x-\mathbf x_0)=0$$

Considering
$$\left(\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}\right)_{P_0}(x-x_0)+\left(\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}\right)_{P_0}(y-y_0)+\left(\frac{\partial f}{\partial z}\right)_{P_0}(z-z_0)=0$$
if $\left(\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}\right)_{P_0}=\color{red}{a}\in \Bbb R$, $\left(\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}\right)_{P_0}=\color{blue}{b}\in \Bbb R$ and
$\left(\frac{\partial f}{\partial z}\right)_{P_0}=\color{magenta}{c}\in \Bbb R$ we have

$$a(x-x_0)+b(y-y_0)+c(z-z_0)=0 \iff $$
$$ax+by+cz-(ax_0+by_0+cz_0)=0 \tag{*}$$

If I denote with $C=ax_0+by_0+cz_0$ the $(*)$ become:

$$\bbox[9px,border:2px solid #F5B041]{\underbrace{F(x,y,z)}_{ax+by+cz}=C}\quad \text{tangent plane in } \Bbb R^3$$

---

If $f \colon A\subseteq \Bbb R^3 → \Bbb R$ is differentiable in
$\mathbf{x}_0\in A$, then the graph of the equation
$$z=f(\mathbf{x}_0)+J_f(\mathbf{x}_0)(\mathbf{x}-\mathbf{x}_0)\equiv f(\mathbf{x}_0)+(\boldsymbol\nabla f)_{P_0}(\mathbf{x}_0)(\mathbf{x}-\mathbf{x}_0)$$
is the tangent hyperplane. Consider that the Jacobian has as matrix elements precisely the components of the gradient:

$$J_f(\mathbf{x}_0)=\begin{bmatrix} \frac{\partial f}{\partial x} & \frac{\partial f}{\partial y} & \frac{\partial f}{\partial z} \end{bmatrix}_{\mathbf{x}_0}$$
Definitively

> You use the transpose symbol, in your question, as you do the row-by-column product.

Comment: Hi, you have considered the domain to be (a subset of) $\mathbb{R}^n$ yet you use $x,y,z$ as the variables. Any particular reason that I do not get?

Comment: @dictatemetokcus I have considered a simple case with be $n=3$ for semplicity.

Comment: @dictatemetokcus Excuse me very much....Often I think in Italian language and to me seem to write in English language :-)

Comment: I have another question: In your opening line, you write (that) the tangent is given by $(\nabla f)_{P_0} \cdot (x - x_0) = 0$ and later you describe the graph as $z = f(x_0) + (\nabla f)_{P_0} \cdot (x - x_0)$. Where do you get the $z$ and $f(x_0)$ from, or rather, what exactly just happened here? I could not follow. Thanks. (Edit: It's alright, I understand the issue with translation. :))

Comment: @dictatemetokcus The tangent hyperplane is a *kind* of surface. In $\Bbb R^2$ it is a classic surface. It can be given in implicit form by the equation $z=f(x,y)$, where  $f$ is definited in an open set $A$ of the cartesian plane. See here, please: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Implicit_surface

Comment: Oh, I didn't see the change of style for $x_0$ and misinterpreted it as the first coordinate of $P_0$, in which case it doesn't make sense. But still, I do not get why it has to be $f(\mathbf{x_0})$ instead of an arbitrary constant $c$.

Comment: @dictatemetokcus It is the same thing: think about the concept of equipotential surface in Physics: *An equipotential surface is a surface on which the potential of a conservative field has constant value*. So you can write also $f(x,y,z)=c\equiv f(\mathbf{x}_0)$, with $c$  a real constant.

Comment: My bad. Thanks for the clarification, it was helpful!

Comment: Hi, I just saw the edit. I would like to point out something: The tangent hyperplane in $\mathbb{R}^3$ indeed has the equation $ax+by+cz=C$ as you wrote, but then the function will have to be $2$ dimensional. Equivalently, the graph in your case will look like $w = f(\mathbb{x}_0) + J_f(\mathbb{x}_0) \cdot (\mathbb{x} - \mathbb{x}_0)$ instead of $z = f(\mathbb{x}_0) + J_f(\mathbb{x}_0) \cdot (\mathbb{x} - \mathbb{x}_0)$. Isn't it so?

Comment: @dictatemetokcus Why should the function be two variables if $F(x,y,z)=ax+by+cz$ have 3 variables hence 3-dimensional?

Comment: Like, $y = f(x)$ has tangent $y = mx + c$, $z = f(x,y)$ has tangent $z = ax + by + c$ and so on. A function of $n$ variables has the equation of tangent of the form $x_{n+1} = \displaystyle \sum_{i = 0}^{n} a_i x_i$

Comment: I would write better $z=(-a/c)x+(-b/c)y+C/c\equiv f(x,y)$.............. :-)

Comment: @dictatemetokcus If $x=0$ in the cartesian plane it is the $y-$axis. In the $\Bbb R^3$, $x=0$ it is a plane ($yz$). Hence $y = -1.25x + 7.5$ in the space $3-$dimensional it is a tangent plane.

Comment: Sorry I deleted the comment because of miscalculation. Here's it again: If $z = f(x,y)$ is the function, then ${\color{magenta} c} = \frac{\partial f}{\partial z} = 1$ right? If we take an example, say $y \equiv f(x)=\frac{5}{x}$ and consider the point $p=(2,2.5)$, then the tangent at that point has the equation $y=-1.25x+5$ but as per your statement, the equation will be: $\left(\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}\right)_p (x-x_0)+\left(\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}\right)_p (y-y_0)=0 \iff \left(\frac{-5}{x^2}\right)_p (x-2)+(1)(y - 2.5)=0 \iff y = \frac{5}{4}x$ which is a different equation.

Comment: I think your equation should instead have been: $\left(\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}\right)_p (x - x_0) + \left(\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}\right)_p (y - y_0) = z - z_0$. Then it even matches with your last equation (the description of the graph). Could you please confirm?

Comment: @dictatemetokcus Hi, you are in 2-dimension and your last assertion is wrong.