# How to find the tangent hyperplane in $n$-dimensions?

Tags: multivariable-calculus

[I asked a similar question a week ago](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4209580/finding-the-tangent-hyperplane-to-a-function-at-a-given-point). I know the equation now but I do not know how to prove that that is indeed the desired equation. I found an [article](https://math.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/Calculus/Book%3A_Vector_Calculus_(Corral)/02%3A_Functions_of_Several_Variables/2.03%3A_Tangent_Plane_to_a_Surface#:%7E:text=Since%20the%20derivative%20dy,out%20to%20be%20the%20case.) which proves the same for $z = f(x,y)$ using vectors.

Can we **prove** this **without using vectors** and (possibly) for $n$-dim?

Using the Frechet derivative, we arrive at $J_f(\mathbf{x}) \cdot h = 0$ for $h \to 0$. Can we continue from here? I am fine with a different method too as long as it does not use vector cross product, etc explicitly.

Comment: I would be tempted to approach this using [differential forms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exterior_derivative), but before this, what do you mean by hyper-plane? A linear equation than constrains Cartesian coordinates and is only fulfilled for points lying on the plane?

Comment: @Cryo In 2D, the tangent is a line, in 3D, it's a 2D plane, I am trying to generalize this. Don't know what exactly should I call it.

Comment: I am not asking for a word, but for a mathematical definition (no rudeness implied :-)). Without this it is hard to answer the question. Let's say you have Cartesian coordinates $x^{(1)},\dots x^{(n)}$ to describe every point in your $n$-dimensional space. Is hyperplane an equation $a_1\,x^{(1)}+\dots+a_n\,x^{(n)}=c$ where $a_{\dots}$ and $c$ are constants?

Comment: @Cryo I think so, yes. Does this look like a line vector or a space? (I am looking for an $(n-1)$ dimensional space.) Can you as well tell me how would a line vector tangent look like in this case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Line, plane etc. are just words unless you have a good definition in your head, and the problem is that these things can be defined in different ways. As far as I see, there is no single best definition, there is only the one that suits you best. Nevertheless, I will try cover what I can

### $n$-dimensional space

Let us agree to work in $\mathbb{R}^n$ space with Cartesian coordinates $x^{(1)}\dots x^{(n)}$. At each point in that space one can trivially obtain $n$-dimensional basis of orthonormal vectors $\mathbf{\hat{x}}_1\dots\mathbf{\hat{x}}_n$ attached to the coordinates.

### $\left(n-1\right)$-dimensional hyperplane in $n$-dimensional space

Let us define hyper-plane as all the points from $\mathbb{R}^n$ that satisfy a linear equation:

$$
hyperplane\left[\left(a_1, \dots a_n\right), c\right]=\Big\{\left(x^{(1)},\dots x^{(n)}\right) \in\mathbb{R}^n \:\Big|\: \sum_i a_i x^{(i)}=c \Big\}
$$

Where $c\in \mathbb{R}$ is a constant, and $a_i \in \mathbb{R}$ are constants with at least one of the $a_i\neq 0$.

Without loss of generality, let $a_n \neq 0$. One can then establish a map from some other $(n-1)$ dimensional $\mathbb{R}^{n-1}$ space, with coordinates $y^{(1)},\dots y^{(n-1)}$:

$$
\begin{align}
\phi &:\mathbb{R}^{n-1} \to \mathbb{R}^n \\
\phi\left(y^{(1)},\dots y^{(n-1)}\right)&=\left(y^{(1)},\dots y^{(n-1)}, \frac{c-\sum_{i=1}^{n-1} a_i y^{(i)}}{a_n}\right)
\end{align}
$$

It should be easy to show that $\phi$ is a bijective map from $\mathbb{R}^{n-1}$ to $
hyperplane\left[\left(a_1, \dots a_n\right), c\right]$ so hyper-plane defined as above can be regarded as $\mathbb{R}^{n-1}$.

A special case of this is $n=2$. In which case a hyper-plane would be all the points that satisfy $a_1 x^{(1)} + a_2 x^{(2)}=c$ which clearly is an equation for a straight line.

### Tangent hyper-plane

Let there now be a sufficiently smooth function $f: \mathbb{R}^n\to \mathbb{R}$. Equation

$$
f\left(x^{(1)},\dots,x^{(n)}\right)=A
$$

will define a surface in $\mathbb{R}^n$. Now consider a curve that lies on this surface. That is, consider a map $\lambda:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}^n$ such that:

$$
f\left(x^{(1)}\left(\lambda\right),\dots,x^{(n)}\left(\lambda\right)\right)=A,\quad \mbox{for all relevant } \lambda 
$$

The tangent to $\lambda$-curve at point $P=\left(x^{(1)}_P,\dots x^{(n)}_P\right)$ is:

$$
\frac{d}{d\lambda}\Big|_P=\sum_{i=1}^n \frac{dx^{(i)}}{d\lambda}\Big|_P \mathbf{\hat{x}}_i
$$

Let us define a tangent hyper-plane to $f=A$ surface at $P$ as all the points one can get to by moving from $P$ along the tangent vector defined by any curve that lies in $f=A$ surface and goes through $P$

$$
T_P f=\Big\{\left(x^{(1)}_P+s\cdot v^{(1)},\dots x^{(n)}_P+s\cdot v^{(n)}\right)\: \Big|\: s\in \mathbb{R},\,v^{(i)}=\frac{d x^{(i)}}{d\lambda}\Big|_P,\,\lambda=\mbox{curve on the surface and going through P}\Big\}
$$

In the above definition, consider what restrictions are placed on $v^{(i)}$. Clearly since $\lambda$-cruve is on the surface:

$$
\begin{align}
f\left(x^{(1)}\left(\lambda\right),\dots,x^{(n)}\left(\lambda\right)\right)&=A \\
\sum_{i=1}^n \frac{\partial f}{\partial x^{(i)}}\Big|_P\cdot\frac{dx^{(i)}}{d\lambda}\Big|_P&=\sum_{i=1}^n \frac{\partial f}{\partial x^{(i)}}\Big|_P\cdot v^{(i)}=0
\end{align}
$$

So if I take a generic point $Q=\left(x^{(1)}_Q,\dots x^{(n)}_Q\right)\in T_p f$ then:

$$
\sum_{i=1}^n \frac{\partial f}{\partial x^{(i)}} \Big|_P\cdot x^{(i)}_Q=\sum_{i=1}^n \frac{\partial f}{\partial x^{(i)}} \Big|_P\cdot x^{(i)}_P + s\cdot \sum_{i=1}^n \frac{\partial f}{\partial x^{(i)}}\Big|_P\cdot v^{(i)}=\sum_{i=1}^n \frac{\partial f}{\partial x^{(i)}} \Big|_P\cdot x^{(i)}_P + 0 = c
$$

Where I have defined constant $c=\sum_{i=1}^n \frac{\partial f}{\partial x^{(i)}} \Big|_P\cdot x^{(i)}_P$ in the last stage. Now also define constants $a_i=\frac{\partial f}{\partial x^{(i)}} \Big|_P$ and you will find that:

$$
T_pf = \Big\{\left(x^{(1)},\dots x^{(n)}\right) \in\mathbb{R}^n \:\Big|\: \sum_i a_i x^{(i)}=c \Big\}
$$

which matches my previous definition of the hyper-plane. I have missed few steps but they should be easy to fill.

### Summary

So in answer to your question. "How do I find the hyper-plane". All you need is constants $c$ and $\{a_i\}$, which can be obtained from the derivatives of $f$ at $P$

---

### Replying to comments

For the purposes of this discussion, $f=A$ defines a manifold embedded into $\mathbb{R}^n$. I talked about tangents to curves on the surface. Each tangent was [tangent vector](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tangent_vector#Definition) the only difference is that I did not make any effort to restrict my discussion to the manifold, i kept it all embedded in $\mathbb{R}^n$. This is indeed the choice you can make. You can restrict your discussion to things intrinsic to the manifold. But then, to talk about vectors on the manifold you need to introduce a concept of tangent space at each point of the manifold. Consider for example a vector pointing to the north in US and in Europe. You can keep these vectors as 3d and then compare them with ease, or you could say that these vectors live in 2d tangent spaces of US and Europe, respectively. You would then need some sort of [connection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levi-Civita_connection) to compare these two vectors.

One thing I did use here was to talk about tangents as derivatives, e.g.

$$
\frac{d}{d\lambda}
$$

for the tangent along the curve parametrized by $\lambda$. This also is the directional derivative, i.e. the operator that, given some function $f$ will return how much this function changes as one moves along the curve, divided by change in $\lambda$.

The answer given by @mathcounterexamples.net is a bit too short to comment, but the answer given in the link you provided more or less boils down to the same thing. Hyperplane corresponds to linear equation parametrized by constants: $\sum_i a_i x^{(i)}=c$ in my notation or $ax+by+cz=C$ in the notation of @Sebastiano.

### PS

It feels to me that you are not too confident about representing vectors as derivatives (along curves), i.e. if I have curve parameterized by $\lambda$ and another one parametrized by $\mu$ and both curves go through some point $P$, at that point I can talk about vectors $\alpha \frac{d}{d\lambda}+\beta\frac{d}{d\mu}$ for constants $\alpha$ and $\beta$. This, for example, could be the tangent vector to curve $x^{(i)}\left(\kappa\right)=x^{(i)}_P+\kappa\cdot\left(\alpha\frac{d x^{(i)}}{d\lambda}\Big|_P+\beta\frac{d x^{(i)}}{d\mu}\Big|_P\right)$ since:

$$
\frac{d}{d\kappa}\Big|_P=\frac{d x^{(i)}}{d\kappa}\Big|_P\frac{\partial}{\partial x^{(i)}}=\left(\alpha\frac{d x^{(i)}}{d\lambda}\Big|_P+\beta\frac{d x^{(i)}}{d\mu}\Big|_P\right)\frac{\partial}{\partial x^{(i)}}=\alpha\frac{d x^{(i)}}{d\lambda}\Big|_P\frac{\partial}{\partial x^{(i)}}+\beta\frac{d x^{(i)}}{d\mu}\Big|_P\frac{\partial}{\partial x^{(i)}}=\alpha\frac{d}{d\lambda}\Big|_P+\beta\frac{d}{d\mu}\Big|_P
$$

Does this make sense? If not, IMHO, it might be a good idea to raise some questions on this matter - I could try answering them.

Comment: That makes a lot of sense. While you have explained it properly, you chose not to use the matrix notation. Could you tell me if there's a difference between the [Tangent Vector](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tangent_vector#Definition), [Directional Derivative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directional_derivative), the equation you wrote and the equation user:mathcounterexamples.net wrote (in the other answer)?

Comment: @dictatemetokcus I have added some comments. I think the answer is growing too long. I would suggest raising new questions rather than appending to this one

Answer (score 0):

The answer you got when $n=3$ can be exactly performed for a larger dimension.

The tangent plane at $z_0$ is given by the hyper plane equation.

$$g(z)= f(z_0)+J_f(z_0)\cdot (z-z_0)$$

Comment: Well I meant, I am looking for a *proof*, not the equation.

Comment: We’ll, a proof depends on definitions. What is your definition of the tangent plane?

Comment: In an $n$-dim space, I am considering the $(n-1)$-dim hyperplane to a function at a (given) point.

Comment: That is not an answer to the question. How do you define the tangent hyperplane to a map at a point?

Comment: Can you tell me if there's a difference between the [Tangent Vector](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tangent_vector#Definition), [Directional Derivative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directional_derivative) and the equation you wrote? Also, what is the dimension of $g(z)$ in your equation?

Comment: I’ll answer to your questions… when you’ll have answer to mine first. Which is just asking you to define a word of the title of your question.

Comment: Sorry, I don't know how to define it, which is why I asked this to you. I might have been able to frame it with one of those I mentioned in my previous comment. I am only trying to extend the "line tangent in 2D, plane tangent in 3D" notion to more than 3 dimensions. The notion is $(n-1)$-dim hyperplane that touches a (given) point $p \in \text{Im}(f)$ at only one point.

Comment: One common definition of the tangent hyperplane is exactly with the equation I provided in my answer. It is indeed an hyperplane providing that the Jacobian doesn’t vanish.

Comment: I see. So can you now tell me (1) the difference between the three terms, if at all they are different? I don't quite see any difference b/w Directional derivative and Tangent Vector. (2) What would the line vector equation at the point $p$ look like?